# How to delete duplicate records while keeping the original in mongodb 5.0

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with ~100k records in it. The documents in it look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c98667d81e1d0270cb3e9"), 
    "name" : "place123", 
    "code" : "XYZ", 
}
```

The problem is, about 10k of those documents have duplicated names. There's two documents with name: "place123", then two with "place456", then maybe three with "place789"...

I have a list with the 12k duplicated names. What I want to do is, for each of those names, delete from the collection every document that contains that name except for one (it doesn't matter whether it's the oldest or the newest), in order to have only one document with name place123, one document with place456, etc.

Since some of those names appear in three documents (while others appear in two), I can't do a deleteOne for each name since in some cases there may still be a duplicate document.

I have tried the following solution I found, lightly modified to account for methods that were deprecated by 5.0:

```
db.collectionName
  .aggregate(
    [
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$name",
          dups: { $push: "$_id" },
          count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
      },
      { $match: { count: { $gt: 1 } } },
    ],
    { allowDiskUse: true }
  )
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.dups.shift();
    db.collectionName.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: doc.dups } });
  });
```

The thing is, when I tested this, the whole collection bar 1 document was deleted, instead of deleting just the duplicated instances as I hoped for. Similar solutions either do nothing or end up with the same result, a total purge of the collection.

Comment: I doubt that `updateMany` deleted anything. Show your actual code. The issue might be in how you are deleting, not the aggregate pipeline.

Comment: @super you're right, it was a deleteMany. Small lapsus when copying and editing in here.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the aggregate pipeline. Unless your data is different to what you expect, or you made some silly mistake somewhere causing it to match everything. Like a typo on `$name` would cause it to match all documents in one big group.

Comment: Now that I say it, sounds kinda likely as you had all documents except one get deleted.

Comment: You could be looking for a simple dedupe pipeline like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rovzlpwYjYI). This will mark all duplicate document with a boolean field `shouldDelete: true`. After executing the pipeline, just do a simple `deleteMany({shouldDelete: true})` to clean up the duplicate records marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$setWindowFields` with `$rank` to compute rank for all documents within the partition `name`. All duplicate documents will have rank greater than 1.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$name",
      "sortBy": {
        "_id": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      rank: {
        $gt: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rank": "$$REMOVE",
      "shouldDelete": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])
```

You can simply execute a `deleteMany` afterwards.

```js
db.collection.deleteMany({"shouldDelete": true});
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rovzlpwYjYI)